# How to simulate a path that exist but cannot be read

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I need to write a test for a method that uses `java.nio.Files.isReadable(Path)`.

How can a path be simulated, which exists but cannot be read?

I cannot create a file (or directory, for that matter) and remove the read privileges for the executing user because then I cannot clean it up after the tests are executed; and I do not say ap way how `Files.isReadable(Path)` could be mocked since it is a static method which is called within the method to be tested.

**UPDATE**: I tried `File#setReadable(false)` but this seems to have no effect.

Comment: Can't you simply create some testing folder structure that stays permanently?

Comment: You can mock static methods using powermock

Comment: @Aziuth Unfortunately, that is not possible for several reasons. The most important is: How would I transport this structure to CI/CD and/or other developers?

Comment: Then how about this idea: you create a demon who works under a different user account, which accepts commands like create or destroy a testing folder structure that is inaccessible to the CI/CD demon. (Don't ask me how this is done, though, never did something like that.)

Comment: @codeflush.dev But the mock would need to be passed to the function I test, right?

Comment: @Hannes no. You just have to set-up your test.See: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic

Answer (score 1):

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("hello", ".tmp");
boolean success = file.setReadOnly();

// and execute your test
// make sure you need to capture various error scenario that might occur during 
   file creation and setting the file to ready only.
```

Comment: @BeUndead It might, according to the API doc, but there is no guarantee. But I am afraid I won't find a better solution so I have to stack to it.

Comment: I stand corrected: That's not a working solution. I need a file wich exists but CAN NOT be read. Let's try setReadable(false).